# Regex Text Cleaning on Multiple forms of text formats

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe with multiple forms of names:

```
JOSEPH W. JASON
Ralph Landau
RAYMOND C ADAMS
ABD, SAMIR
ABDOU TCHOUSNOU, BOUBACAR
ABDL-ALI, OMAR R
```

For first 3, the rule is last word. For the last three, or anything with comma, the first word is the last name. However, for name like Abdou Tchousnou, I only took the last word, which is Tchousnou.

The expected output is

```
JASON
LANDAU
ADAMS
ABD
TCHOUNOU
ABDL-ALI
```

The left is the name, and the right is what I want to return.

```
str.extract(r'(^(?=[^,]*,?$)[\w-]+|(?<=, )[\w-]+)', expand=False)
```

Is there anyway to solve this? The current code only returns the first name instead of surname which is the one that I want.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What is the rule here? How do you determine it is the last name? Non-whitespaces before `,` or end of string? If yes, try `(\S+)(?![^,])` (or `(\S+)(?=,|$)`)

Comment: Now, you may use `(^[^,]+(?=,)|\S+$)`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
(.+(?=,)|\S+$)
```

- `(` - start capture group #1
- `.+(?=,)` - get everything before a comma
- `|` - or
- `\S+$` - get everything which is not a whitespace before the end of the line
- `)` - end capture group #1

https://regex101.com/r/myvyS0/1

Python:

```
str.extract(r'(.+(?=,)|\S+$)', expand=False)
```

Comment: `Series.str.extract` requires a capturing group around the pattern part that will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex to extract:

```
>>> print (df)
                       name
0           JOSEPH W. JASON
1              Ralph Landau
2           RAYMOND C ADAMS
3                ABD, SAMIR
4  ABDOU TCHOUSNOU, BOUBACA
5          ABDL-ALI, OMAR R

>>> df['name'].str.extract(r'([^,]+(?=,)|\w+(?:-\w+)*(?=$))', expand=False)
0            JASON
1           Landau
2            ADAMS
3              ABD
4  ABDOU TCHOUSNOU
5         ABDL-ALI
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(`: Start capture group

  - `[^,]+(?=,)`: Match 1+ non-comma characters tha
  - `|`: OR
  - `\w+`: Match 1+ word charcters
  - `(?:-\w+)*`: Match `-` followed 1+ word characters. Match 0 or more of this group
- `)`: End capture group
- `(?=,|$)`: Lookahead to assert that we have comma or end of line ahead

Comment: Your regex doesn't work for me. https://regex101.com/r/N0cLHt/1

Comment: sorry for the additional question. For name 'ABDOU TCHOUSNOU, BOUBACAR', is there anyway I extract anything before ','? like 'ABDOU TCHOUSNOU'?  instead of only TCHOUSNOU? The rest should stay the same. Thank you!

Comment: @LearningCode You should update your question to reflect that detail so that others can properly answer...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: It works fine, you have to turn `g` mode off and test every line separately. This is how `extract` works here

Comment: @LearningCode: What is special rule for `ABDOU TCHOUSNOU, BOUBACAR`? Should `BOUBACAR` be part of regex?

Comment: No for thisone, the current return is TCHOUSNOU, I need both ABDOU TCHNOUSNOU...so basically if a comma, anything before comma I will need

Comment: @LearningCode I updated my answer per your details.

Comment: @LearningCode: btw your expected output showed `TCHOUNOU` in question